# Unity3d reach images from folder

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been looking for a while now but can't find how to reach stuffs from my unity folder in my C# scripts. I don't want to add them as a parameter but rather just be able to find a specific image from a folder called Images in my unity project.
Is this possible?

Comment: did you mean this? http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html

Comment: yeah that will probably work! found this tutorial about that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTDy-A7gfSc